# how to insert missing data in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python,i have to solve this use case.Will you guys please help me to solve this?

This is my json file

```
{"data":[{"id":"77","value":"hello"},{"id":"5","value":"HI"},{"id":"1","value":"whats up"},{"id":"2","value":"what"},{"id":"120","value":"hello"},{"id":"170","value":"hello"},{"id":"190","value":"hello"}]}
```

Firstly i need to convert this json file into dataframe?

```
with open('Sample.json') as f:
data = json.load(f,cls=Decoder)
print(data)

list=[]
list=(data['data']) 


df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['id','value'])
print(df.sort_values(by=['id']))
```

output should look like this!!!

**IN the ascending order**
 [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV0kt.jpg)

Upto this was done:

After this i need you guys help like...
in Column id {1,2,5,77,120,170,190} and respective values in values column.
i have to add all the missing rows respective to id and values should be only space..
from id '1' to id '190'
like id column should look like {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..............,77....120..170...190} here in between 2 and 5 missing numbers that 3 and 4 and value column should be empty or space only.
output look like

```
id value
1   whats up
2   what
3   space
4   space
5   hi
6   space
.
.
.
77  hello
.
.
.
upto 190
```

IF possible attach the code..

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066608/adding-values-to-existing-columns-in-pandas/50066824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For json to dictionary you can directly use json normalize and then apply set_index on it and set id as index. Then on the new dataframe apply np.re_index and np.arange

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = [{"id":77,"value":"hello"},{"id":5,"value":"HI"},{"id":1,"value":"whats up"},{"id":2,"value":"what"},{"id":120,"value":"hello"},{"id":170,"value":"hello"},{"id":190,"value":"hello"}]
df = json_normalize(data)
new_df = df.set_index('id')
new_df.reindex(np.arange(df.id.min(), df.id.max() + 1)).fillna('space')
```

Comment: It will really solve the second issue like filling the missing integer in the id column? i already converted to dataframe from json. i want to fill the missing integers! please

Comment: I'm working on the 2nd part but for the 1st instead you can use this

Comment: @user11646543 just check I've updated the code with what you want and if you want to use your code for json to dataframe for missing values you just need to add last line and it will work.

Comment: as you have asked you would always want integer 190 use: df.reindex(np.arange(df.id.min(), 190)).fillna('space')

Comment: Sure thanks mate !!! I will just try this and let you know for the further queries

Comment: Sure just let me know if you face any issue and btw if you want to use your code for json to dict just add last two lines in your code and you will get the desired output with missing entries

Comment: Yeah sure!! And will you please explain me that last two lines of code what was the logic ? Please and also explain me if possible that what json-normalize function will do? Thanks

Comment: As you want from I'd 1 to 190, np.arange is used for getting value in specific interval and then we apply np.reindex which conform data frame to new index. By default it will put NaN in all  missing entries other than mentioned in your json. As you want "space" we use fillna which will insert space in all missing entries.    https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: json_normalize is used for converting json to dataframe

Comment: Cool thanks for the efforts!!! Another query like in your code that first reindex()method will execute then .fillna() method executing right?? Because where did you mention the column name value to to fill the space?we have to select the column right to proceed with fillna() method?

Comment: yes first the reindex will execute and by default in the missing entries it will insert NaN and as you want "space" in the missing entries we use fillna. So wherever there is NaN it will replace with "space"

Answer (score 1):

One you way to work with this is to define an object from your json and then put it into the dataframe with `pd.read_json()`. Finally use `sort_values()` to sort it ascending. Afterwards, I find no better option than to create a `support_df` that will be used to add the extra rows that are needed and finally `np.where` to either keep the value corresponding to the original `df` or use `space` from `support_df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
data = {"data":[{"id":"77","value":"hello"},{"id":"5","value":"HI"},{"id":"1","value":"whats up"},{"id":"2","value":"what"},{"id":"120","value":"hello"},{"id":"170","value":"hello"},{"id":"190","value":"hello"}]}
j = json.dumps(data)
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data),orient='split').sort_values(['id'])

support_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(min(df['id']),max(df['id']+1)),'value_aux':'space'})
final_df = support_df.merge(df,how='left')
final_df['value'] = np.where(final_df['value'].isna(),final_df['value_aux'],final_df['value'])
final_df = final_df.drop(columns='value_aux')
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
      id     value
0      1  whats up
1      2      what
2      3     space
3      4     space
4      5        HI
..   ...       ...
185  186     space
186  187     space
187  188     space
188  189     space
189  190     hello
```

Comment: This is done already. i need to fill the missing rows with integers

Comment: yeah !! thanks !! I am also trying to solve the second part only.Tell me reset_index method?Will work here

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It's working and tell me one last thing what logic you have used .. did you create another dataframe with column id contains from 1 to 190 and all the cells value is space and then you joined two dataframes into one using merge ?? Is it right? Or make me understand the code please?

Comment: support_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(min(df['id']),max(df['id']+1)),'value_aux':'space'}) In this piece of code. You mentioned max(df['id'+1]) right but i dont want the value which is maximum in my json id's i want always integer 190 only could you suggest me to change to code

Comment: Yes if you want 190 as max value, regardless of the value in the json, you can simply hardcode the 190 in the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) (to create the complete list of indexes you want) to create blank rows based on which values are missing in the id column. (You'll have to [set the id column as the index first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.iloc[-1]` to add the missing values and you can use `json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)`  to read the `json` file

```
data ={"data":[{"id":"77","value":"hello"},{"id":"5","value":"HI"},{"id":"1","value":"whats up"},{"id":"2","value":"what"},{"id":"120","value":"hello"},{"id":"170","value":"hello"},{"id":"190","value":"hello"}]}
print(data)

list=[]
list=(data['data']) 


df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['id','value'])

df.iloc[-1]=[5,"go"] # here you can add any other DataFrame 
print(df.sort_values(by=['id']))
```