# How to add numpy array values to dataframe at a certain index?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe `df` with 200 rows, and numpy array `my_array` with 15 values.

```
my_array = [41892.79355875, 40239.97933262, 39466.32169404, 38416.39545664,
            40012.3803004, 41135.45946026, 43084.18917943, 44825.08405799,
            44066.70603561, 46636.34415037, 45855.25783352, 45863.87118957,
            44697.45547342, 48065.5708295, 47931.83508874]
```

When I add the values of `my_array` into `df` under new column `column_2`, the 15 values get added into the first 15 rows of `df`.

```
df['column_2'] = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns=['column_2'])
```

How do I make the code add the values of `my_array` into the **last** 15 rows of `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now another problem is that you also erase all others values of the column, you may not set a `DataFrame` but just the array as the new value.

To set values in a column, at specific index, use `df.loc[df.index[#], 'NAME']`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2] for _ in range(100)], columns=['column_1', 'column_2'])
my_array = np.array([41892.79355875, 40239.97933262, 39466.32169404, 38416.39545664,
                     40012.3803004, 41135.45946026, 43084.18917943, 44825.08405799,
                     44066.70603561, 46636.34415037, 45855.25783352, 45863.87118957,
                     44697.45547342, 48065.5708295, 47931.83508874])

df.loc[df.index[-15:], 'column_2'] = my_array

print(df)
```

```
    column_1      column_2
0          1      2.000000
1          1      2.000000
2          1      2.000000
3          1      2.000000
4          1      2.000000
..       ...           ...
95         1  45855.257834
96         1  45863.871190
97         1  44697.455473
98         1  48065.570830
99         1  47931.835089
```

Comment: Thank you, could you look at the edited post to see how I can place the values in an already existing column?

Comment: please help with this

Comment: @LisaS I don't really get exactly what you ask

Comment: I want the values being displayed in `Predicted` to be displayed in `Prediction` which has Nan values right now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066608/adding-values-to-existing-columns-in-pandas like this but I don't know how to do mine

Comment: You can use `dict = {}`

Comment: @azro `np.full` can do the job instead of for loop, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html